# When comparing two or more, is it "chart of accounts" or "charts of accounts"

Tags: grammaticality

Company A has set up its own Chart of Accounts, as has Company B. I am going to write about the ways we can compare them. It seems to my ear they should treated like 'mothers-in-law,' with the 'chart' also plural, but open like 'attorneys general.' So:

'The two companies may use quite different **charts** of accounts.'

I can't find it readily in Merriam-Webster. What's your view?
Many thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'chart of account', so one doesn't have an option about pluralising the word "accounts"; it can only be plural. So for multiples, "chart" must of course be pluralised, so "charts of accounts" is the only possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you would pluralize charts, but its worth noting that this is not the same as 'mothers in law.' In that phrase, mothers is pluralized while law is left singular, because the word 'law' is being used as a noncount noun, the concept of law in its entirety, rather than multiple individual laws. In 'charts of accounts,' there are multiple accounts and there are also multiple charts. This is why both should be pluralized.

Comment: Many thanks, kingfrito! I've had others-in-law on the brain today, but I knew my 'accounts' should always be plural.

Comment: The last line of your answer is potentially misleading. You see, there is no such thing as a 'chart of account', so one doesn't have an option about pluralising the word "accounts"; it can only be plural. For multiples, "chart" must of course be pluralised, so "charts of accounts" is the only possibility.

Comment: @BillJ I see what your saying. Im not really sure how to remove that confusion though. Feel free to edit it if better phrasing comes to your mind.